# Why does the thermal equilibrium change so quickly?

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium

I performed an experiment recently where I tested the specific heat capacity of different metals in water. Once the metals were removed from a beaker and placed into calorimeter with water, thermal equilibrium occurred very quickly. Why is it that thermal equilibrium is achieved so quick when a calorimeter is used?

Comment: I should add that if you repeat the experiment with non metals, they should have the same mass and same shape to the degree possible given the differences in densities.

Answer (score 2):

Its because you were testing metals. They have high thermal conductivity and hence heat transfers through them quickly to the water. Try the experiment with non-metals, e.g., plastics. You'll find it takes longer to reach thermal equilibrium.

Hope this helps